# How to make possible to return structs of different types from one function with Golang?

Tags: go

I have a function which queries database, then, depending on result form it, can create a struct `OrderWithoutDetails` or `OrderWithDetails` depending on the presence of details about the order.

How do I make the function to be able to return result of both types?

Comment: On what depends, whether you will get details or not? If you know that when you call the function, is better to have 2 different functions. If not, and OrderWith/WithoutDetails is nearly the same, you can write a function, func findOrder (Order, *[]Detail, error), that returns details or nil. Also you can put *Details to order. And also fine is return interface{}, or better interface, that returns you details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `interface{}`

```
func queryDb() interface{}{

}
```

But the better will be if your 2 type of struct can have a common function, that can satisfy a common interface, it will be cleaner.
Example :

```
type s1 struct{
  id int
  name string
}

type s2 struct{
  id int
  age int
}

type reDB interface {
  my_print()
}

func (r *s1) my_print(){
  fmt.Print(s1.id)
}

func (r *s2) my_print(){
  fmt.Print(s1.id)
}

func queryDb() reDB{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Underscores in names are not idiomatic in Go.  Go uses CamelCase, not snake_case.  This is particularly important because, in your example, the interface `reDB` and the `my_print()` function within it are not exported, and thus cannot be accessed outside the defining package.

Comment: Yep, I knew for the `CamelCase`, I wrote quickly, with my practice from C.
But it has nothing to do with exported or not, only the first letter has something to do with, and `CamelCase` is not `PascalCase`. Plus here we don't care about exported or not, maybe he doesn't want to export these func / var ;)